# Why can't I do math with my dictionary values in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, yfinance

I'm trying to average out the bid + ask for yfinance. So far I've got this: `price = ({info['bid']} + {info['ask']}) / 2`

but that returns an error saying it's the wrong datatype(set). But if I assign them to variables and print them, it seems as if they're floats. How do I get the float that's returned and do math with it?

Comment: Hello OffxcialBubba! I think you meant by like this `price = (info['bid'] + info['ask']) / 2`

Comment: So when do you use the curly brackets? Are those just for printing f strings? If they are then I feel so dumb right now

Comment: `I feel so dumb right now` don't be :) Well these `{` & `}` are used for `python dictionaries` & `sets`.

Comment: [python sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)
[python dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

There are a lot of uses of these `{` & `}`, based on your code you're just semantically wrong but no worries we all got that when we try something new :)

Comment: Ideally, you should be posting the original error, with the traceback, and with the lines of your code being referenced in the traceback. Otherwise, you will only find us trying to guess what's going on, and our guesses could be very wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a dictionary called `info` with the information.
To access the information you use `info["bid"]` or `info["ask"]`.

```
price = (info["bid"] + info["ask"]) / 2
```

You created a `set` containing the information before adding them up, and mathematics is not supported between two `set`.